# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable , how can i solve it?

Tags: python, pygame

i`m trying to make a game , but this error happens with my collision def

thats the code:

```
def colisao(espeto):
   for b in range(len(espeto)) :
     if player.collided(espeto[b]):
        if b == 0 :
            espeto [0].x = janela.width / 2
            espeto [0].y = janela.height - espeto [0].height
        elif b == 1:
            espeto [b].y = janela.height - espeto [0].height
            espeto [b].x = espeto [0].x + janela.width / 3

        elif b != 1:
             espeto [b].y = janela.height - espeto [0].height
             espeto [b].x = janela.width / 2 + espeto [b - 1].x
```

then i put in the game loop this function

```
is_colliding = colisao(espeto_f1)
```

and when i execute , this happens :/

PS : Sorry for bad english , i`m learning the language , yet

Comment: Could you provide a full stack trace? The entire error message?

Comment: Is the space between espeto and [0] and espeto and [b] actually there? If so you need to remove it. Also, in python you can actually iterate lists so you can do for b, item in enumerate(espeto) and use b for index and item as espeto[b]. Other than that, are janela and player defined?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that `player.collided` is None, instead of a function/method. Please check that. This is the only thing I can guess with the details given.

Comment: the strange think is... if i put the code in the loop with the right variable , it works

Comment: Can you please inspect, say print, the value of player.collided , is it None or a function? Also note about the spaces in between `espeto` and `[b] as also mention in comments.

Comment: it says none , but with the print it works , now I know nothing whats going on :/

Comment: What was the problem?